# Hibernation on elementaryOS

Tags: suspend, laptop

I am trying to let my XPS 13 7390 hibernate when closing the lid.

I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend/781957#781957) to set my system up to do this. But I think it is not working properly.

When I run `sudo systemctl suspend-then-hibernate` I can see new "hibernation" logs, when running `cat /var/log/syslog | grep hibernate`:

```
Dec  8 14:04:16 jonas-XPS-13-7390 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend; Idle into hibernate...
Dec  8 14:05:32 jonas-XPS-13-7390 systemd[1]: Started Suspend; Idle into hibernate.
Dec  8 14:05:32 jonas-XPS-13-7390 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend; Idle into hibernate.
Dec  8 14:05:32 jonas-XPS-13-7390 systemd[1]: suspend-then-hibernate.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Dec  8 14:05:32 jonas-XPS-13-7390 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend; Idle into hibernate.
```

And searching for "sleep" I get the following lines:

```
Dec  8 14:04:16 jonas-XPS-13-7390 systemd-sleep[11380]: Suspending system...
Dec  8 14:05:32 jonas-XPS-13-7390 systemd-sleep[11380]: System resumed.
```

**But when i close the lid, or press the power button, NO new hibernation is logged.** But when i search for the term "sleep" it shows the same logs as when i've run the hibernation command manually from terminal:

```
Dec  8 14:10:51 jonas-XPS-13-7390 systemd-sleep[12481]: Suspending system...
Dec  8 14:11:29 jonas-XPS-13-7390 systemd-sleep[12481]: System resumed.
```

Now I want to know:

- How can I find out if my system was actually hibernating (using less energy than sleeping is my main focus here)?
- How can I make my elementary installation sleep when closing the lid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the solution to the problem in "Linux Magazin".

My full workflow looks like this:

## Lid Hibernate Ubuntu

- Make sure you have SWAP > RAM

### SWAP to fstab

find swap UUID:

```
blkid | grep swap
```

should output

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="90ee7315-b16a-4e2g-bd07-cg83703750b9" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="abadca41-942a-6c83-88d2-db28cf41ce13"`
```

copy the UUID, without the " :

`UUID=90ee7315-b16a-4e2g-bd07-cg83703750b9`

add swap to fstab

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

add

`UUID=90ee7315-b16a-4e2g-bd07-cg83703750b9 none            swap    sw              0       0`

- reboot

### add swap to grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

edit
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
to
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=90ee7215-c16a-4e2f-bd07-cd83703750b6"`

if you DONT want kernel messages to be shown and keep the plymouth animation during boot, change to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=90ee7215-c16a-4e2f-bd07-cd83703750b6"
```

update grub with the new settings:
`sudo update-grub`

try with

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

after reboot it should show all the same windows again

### activate automatic hibernation after delay

To start using this function you need to create a file

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/sleep.conf
```

add

```
[Sleep]
HibernateDelaySec=3600
```

try

```
sudo systemctl suspend-then-hibernate
```

Should sleep for the time specified and then the screen turns on shortly and it hibernates. Try rebooting after this happened.

If it works make it permanent.

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

change

```
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

to

```
HandleSuspendKey=suspend-then-hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=suspend-then-hibernate
```

Save the file. Restart logind service by the command:

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

sources:

- Linux Magazin 01/20, S.72
- almost similar: [How to hibernate Freya?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/920/how-to-hibernate-freya)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend/781957#781957

Comment: I have already tried all of this with no success. Can you mark your answer as the accepted one in order to be usefull for somebody else?

Comment: @Borislav Do you have your swap encrypted?

Comment: no, it is not. I have tried all the steps you describe following a lot of different guides, but when I execute `systemctl hibernate` the screen becomes black, after a second or something it lights again and then after like couple of seconds it turns off. When I start the computer, it is like normal boot, the swap is empty but I see a messages for a lot of orphaned inodes, just like if I do hard shutdown by holding the poweroff button. If I execute `systemctl suspend-then-hibernate`, first it suspends, and after the delay specified it behave the same way..

Comment: @Borislav do you have a duplicate GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in /etc/default/grub ? I had a duplicate one and realised it was overwriting my GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT so none of the settings there were picked up.

Comment: I have GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet......" and  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" but I do not think that they are duplicates, are they?

Comment: just tried all of this with the ubuntu 20.04 and it works without any clue, it looked like I have messed out somehow my elementary system and only my answer above works. I will keep it here also as an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve hibernation following one guide, but I did some changes noticed into the comments to the post there. Sources are below, but first the steps with the updated (working) for me code:

## 1. Edit the hibernation service with

```
sudo systemctl edit systemd-hibernate.service
```

## 2. Paste the following code

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStartPre=-/bin/run-parts -v -a pre -a hibernate /lib/systemd/system-sleep
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk
ExecStartPost=-/bin/run-parts -v --reverse -a post -a hibernate /lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

Save <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and exit with <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

## 3. Update systemd

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

## 4. Test if it is working

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

After the above command the screen should go into terminal view, a counter shows the progress of the disk write into swap partition and computer turns off. When I start it the procedure is like a normal start of the system but there is no login screen (pantheon-greeter) - after the plymouth animation the system is restored to the state with opened windows and settings applied before the hibernation command.

**If everything works well for you** too, you can add this functionality when the lid is closed - edit the logind.conf file, because there is no such an option into System settings - Power anymore:

## 5. Set hibernation on a lid close

```
sudoedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

find and edit the line at the end of the file with `HandleLidSwitch=whatever_you_choosed_from_power_settings`, if there is a comment (a `#` sign in front) remove it or just paste below:

```
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save and close the file. In order the changes to take effect immediately - `sudo service systemd-logind restart` or just reboot the computer.

I have tried doing the same with suspend-then-hibernate, but if I edit the suspend-then-hibernate.service like this, ofcourse it do not suspend first but immidately hibernates and if I do not edit it but try to execute the `systemctl suspend-then-hibernate` command - after the sleep interval it executes the default hibernation process which do not work on my system - it leads to a shutdown with orphaned inodes, which is not nice.

**Sources:**

*hibernation* - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386837/355963 - notice the comments of the post

*lid close* - https://askubuntu.com/a/372616/730454

@zagatta-sonah Thanks for asking this question and sharing your attempt - it inspired me to found at least this functionality I spent days of not successfull tries, because on my system suspend is not nice on a battery power for a long time.

If somebody can share how to achieve **suspend-then-hibernate** the same way it will be really nice, but at least only hibernate is much much better than just suspend.

Comment: i think i found the solution. see what i answered for my own question.

Regards for your input